# LGHUB Lua Play and abort maccro

Tags: lua, macros, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have a G513 keyboard. I was using the LGS before the LGHUB software. And I was using LUA to stop my running macros instantly(it has to be done with that way since macros doesn't stop until they finish their loop once).

That was my solution while I was using LGS(old software), F5(G5) was my toggle key:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg, family)

OutputLogMessage("clicked event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg);



if ( event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 5 ) then


        ToggleState = not ToggleState


    if ToggleState then


        PlayMacro("macro1");


    else

        AbortMacro()

            end
        end
    end
```

But for some reason(which I can't figure it out) it doesn't work anymore in the LGHUB. How can I fix this?

I tried everything...

Comment: What is the type of your macro?  You have set it when created the macro.

Comment: It is a toggle macro which loops nearly about every 15 seconds. Sometimes I want it to stop in the middle of the loop but it doesnt't stop until it finishes the whole loop. Thats why I was trying to Play-Abort it with LUA. It was working fine with the previous, old version of the logitech gaming software but since they cancelled LGS I have to use LGHUB but some reason the same lua script doesn't work for LGHUB.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  GHub interrupts a macro in the middle as expected.  My macro is slowly typing "abcdef" string, and I can stop it after "abc".  Make sure you have not accidentally bound this macro to a key.

Comment: What is your GHub version?

Comment: V2022.10.326382

Comment: GHUB never stops a keystroke macro in the middle of its loop unless you use lua to abort the macro. It was working fine with the old software("Play-Abort Macro"). Maybe its different with the text macros. My macro is something like press x-wait 250ms, press 3-wait 850 ms, etc. hits like 20-30 keys like this with custom delays.